# YUI3 YQL using limit and sort together

Tags: javascript, json, yui, yql, yui3

I have a YQL query that combines a bunch of RSS feeds and then sorts them by date.  It's working great, but I would like to be able to paginate the results.

Here is my query:

```
select channel.item.title, channel.item.link, channel.item.pubDate, channel.item.description(0) from xml where url in(... urls go here ...) | unique(field='channel.item.link') | sort(field='channel.item.pubDate', descending='true')
```

The problem is that yql executes LIMIT and OFFSET before the sort filter.  So if I have a LIMIT 5 I end up with only the first 5 items from the first RSS feed in the list ... not the first 5 items of all my combined feeds.

Is there a way to chain queries, so I can get all my query that sorts all the results and the call a query that limits my results.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the truncate(count=5) to get the first 5 items of the filtered feed.

```
select channel.item.title, channel.item.link, channel.item.pubDate, channel.item.description(0) from xml where url in(... urls go here ...) | unique(field='channel.item.link') | sort(field='channel.item.pubDate', descending='true') | truncate(count=5)
```

Or the tail() method with a reversed sort (posted above) would work as well.

See http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

What about using `tail()` and additionally `sort()` in the other direction?

Something like this:

```
select channel.item.title, channel.item.link, channel.item.pubDate, channel.item.description(0) from xml where url in(... urls go here ...) | unique(field='channel.item.link') | sort(field='channel.item.pubDate', descending='false') | tail(count=5)
```

I have not tried this and I am not sure which sort order you need but you can for sure use `tail()`. There is no equivalent `head()` function apparently, so make sure the newest items are are the end after your sorting.

For further information see
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/sorting.html